# Django loaddata and 'invalid model identifier' error

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have this dump.json with data from a Django-project that I'm trying to load (manage.py loaddata) into another project where I've set up the same model/fields etc. The problem is the "app" is not named the same in the two projects. So I get this 'invalid model identifier' -error.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply change the app name in the JSON and be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so and tried to write a small script to iterate and change this on 500+ json objects in the file but I think there was some other attributes in it that complicated the whole thing so I ended up redoing everything from scratch. Thanks anyway